# how to manage non renewable subscription if iCloud is not configured on device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

In my app i am implementing non renewable subscription.
I am using iCloud to make it available on all ios devices of that user. So when user is trying to purchase any service i am checking if iCloud is enabled or not. If enabled then IAP view will be displayed otherwise an alert will popup saying that 'you need to enable iCloud to purchase this product'.
But i am not sure if apple is going to accept it or not.
I dont want to use user registration method. So i just wanted to know if asking user to enable iCloud to buy product is safe or not. If it is not then what is the best way to manage non renewable subscriptions using iCloud.